# How can I calculate the AVG of the below CTE?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to find the average of a query which has 600,000 rows. I have created a CTE to calculate distances based off of longitude and latitude. Is it possible for me to add an aggregate function to this, as the calculated_distance is not an existing column?

Thanks in advance!

```
WITH name AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        latitude,
        longitude,
        name,
        docks
    FROM
        santander_stations
),
ride_data AS (
    SELECT
        startstationid,
        endstationid
    FROM
        public.santander_2016

    UNION

    SELECT
        startstationid,
        endstationid
    FROM
        public.santander_2017

    UNION
        
    SELECT
        startstationid,
        endstationid
    FROM
        public.santander_2018
)
SELECT
    calculate_distance( a.latitude, a.longitude, b.latitude, b.longitude, 'K' ),
    a.name AS Start_Station,
    b.name AS End_Station
FROM
    name AS a,
    name AS b
WHERE
    a.id IN ( SELECT startstationid FROM ride_data )
    AND
    b.id IN ( SELECT endstationid   FROM ride_data )
ORDER BY
    1 DESC
```

Comment: 1) I am not seeing `calculated_distance`. I do see `calculate_distance`. Is that what you are referring to? 2) `calculate_distance` looks to be a function. What is it doing? **Add information as update to question**

Comment: Using `FROM name AS a, name AS b` is going to mess-up your query regardless. You should always use an explicit `JOIN` instead.

Comment: Hi Adrian, thanks for your reply. I ended up exporting to excel and calculating the mean that way. Although it didn’t like the 600,000 rows very much. 

The calculate_distance is what I was referring to, and it is working as a function. I would have liked to have been able to find the average using SQL of this field. 

The function is calculating the distance in km’s from a.longitude and a.latitude to b.longitude and b.latitude. 

The result was the distance between each station, however I couldn’t see where I could fit an aggregate function into this query.

Comment: now you have 2 cte, assume now your query is correct, so you can make the last select query as CTE. finally you can select start_station, end_station,sum(calculate_distance) from last cte group by 1,2.

Answer (score 0):

The number of rides is much more than the number of possible start & end stations. Therefore, we can calculate the distances of all combinations of (start station, end station) first, and then use the result as a lookup table for the 600,000 rides.

Here's a way to calculate the average ride distance in year 2016, 2017 and 2018 (please replace (1). the `distance_km` formula with your `calculated_distance()` UDF, (2). `Santander_rides` with your `ride_data` subquery)

```sql
with cte_santander_station_distance as (
select x.id            as start_station_id,
       y.id            as end_station_id,
       acos(sin(x.latitude)*sin(y.latitude)+cos(x.latitude)*cos(y.latitude)*cos(y.longitude-x.longitude)) as distance_km
  from santander_stations x, santander_stations y
 where x.id <> y.id)
 select avg(ssd.distance_km) as average_distance_km,
        count(*)             as rides
   from santander_rides sr 
   join cte_santander_station_distance ssd
     on sr.start_station_id = ssd.start_station_id
    and sr.end_station_id   = ssd.end_station_id;
```

If there're lots of combinations of start station and end station, you can materialize the lookup table such as below:

[image]